# ADF copy task field type boolean as lowercase

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADF i have a copy task that copies data from JSON to Delimited text, i get the result as

```
A | B | C
"name"|False|"description"
```

Json record is like

```
{"A":"name","B":"false","C":"description"}
```

Excepted result is as below

```
A | B | C
"name"|false|"description"
```

[image]

The bool value have to be in lowercase in the resulting Delimited text file, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this.  The reason is you are converting the string to the ADF dataytpe "Boolean" which for some reason renders the values in Proper case.

Do you really have a receiving process which is case-sensitive?  If you need to maintain the case of the source value simply remove the mapping, ie

[image: ADF designer]

If you do need some kind of custom mapping, then simply change the mapping data type to `String` and not `Boolean`.

**UPDATE after new JSON provided**

OK, so your first json sample has the "false" value in quotes so is treated as a string. In your second example, your json "true" is not in quotes so is a genuine json boolean value. ADF is auto-detecting this at run time and it seems like it can not be over-ridden as far as I can tell. Happy to be corrected. As an alternative, consider altering your original json to a string, as per you original example OR copying the file to Blob Store or Azure Data Lake, runniing some transform on it (eg Databricks) and then outputting the file. Alternately consider Mapping Data Flows.

Comment: this pipleine will be a replacement to an existing system. The existing system accepts bools in lowercase. I did try to clear the mapping in copy task, the result file has bool values as string("true"). Then i changed the source JSON field C to bool, now the source value will be "C": true after the copy task this value will again be True in the delimited text without any mapping in the copy task.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  If I have a source JSON file (as per your json file), with a lower case value like false, and I copy that to a text file with no mapping, the value remains lower case in the text file.  Can you add a screenprint of your source file and the output, and your expected results please?

Comment: Source JSON:
{"modifiedby":"f6ae592d-b1f0-e811-bcee-005056bd6378",,"new_revisevalue":true,"name":"ADMON"}

Result:
modifiedby|new_revisevalue|name
"f6ae592d-b1f0-e811-bcee-005056bd6378"|True|"ADMON"

Expected result:
modifiedby|new_revisevalue|name
"f6ae592d-b1f0-e811-bcee-005056bd6378"|true|"ADMON"

Comment: OK, so your first json sample has the "false" value in quotes so is treated as a string.  In your second example, your json "true" is not in quotes so is a genuine json boolean value.  ADF is auto-detecting this at run time and it seems like it can be over-ridden as far as I can tell.  Happy to be corrected.  As an alternative, consider altering your original json to a string, as per you original example OR copying the file to Blob Store or Azure Data Lake, runniing some transform on it (eg Databricks) and then outputting the file.  Alternately consider Mapping Data Flows.

Comment: Hi @MarkKromer, is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: Hi @JayGong, is there a way to override this behaviour?